# mysql connectionAttributes time_zone

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, rds, connector-j

I am prototyping using MySQL within RDS in AWS.  Our code currently uses Oracle.  It uses a connection pool API that we don't have direct control of without impacting other users.  The oracle database is set for US/Eastern timezone.  The MySQL database is set for UTC.  Rather than change all the code to deal with UTC when it's written for US/Eastern I'm looking for a way to either a) change the database server to use US/Eastern or b) to set attributes in the connection URL to set all connections to convert from UTC to US/Eastern.

When I use the mysql command line tool I can set time_zone = 'US/Eastern and that works for the connection.  I've tried to set it globally but I don't have permission and I can't give myself permission to do so within my instance in AWS.

In the documentation for the URL string for MySQL connector J I've looked at all of the timezone related attributes but nothing seems to be what I need.  I tried connectionAttributes=time_zone:US/Eastern but that doesn't work.

Is there magic in AWS to create the instance with a different timezone that I didn't notice when creating my instance?

I've looked for a way within AWS to change the database server's timezone but no luck there.  Did I miss something?

Is there a way with the URL string to do this as with the mysql command line client?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-change-time-zone/

Comment: Thanks Mark!  That did the trick and I learned about some AWS documentation I didn't know existed.  Got my db upgraded to 5.7 at the same time.